# R - find and return an ID's counterpart

Tags: r

I have a dataset with many groups of 12 players. Each of the 12 players within a group are assigned a pair number which pairs them with a partner from their group that has been assigned the same pair number. I would like to create a new column that identifies the partner's player ID. For example with 2 groups of 4 players:

```
df <- data.frame(group_id = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2), player_id = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8), player_pair = c(1,2,1,2,2,2,1,1))

#  group_id player_id player_pair
#1        1         1           1
#2        1         2           2
#3        1         3           1
#4        1         4           2
#5        2         5           2
#6        2         6           2
#7        2         7           1
#8        2         8           1
```

I would like the resulting table to look like:

```
#  group_id player_id player_pair counterpart_ID
#1        1         1           1              3
#2        1         2           2              4
#3        1         3           1              1
#4        1         4           2              2
#5        2         5           2              6
#6        2         6           2              5
#7        2         7           1              8
#8        2         8           1              7
```

Answer (score 1):

Grouped by group_id, player_pair, get the `rev`erse of player_id to create the counterpart_ID

```
library(dplyr) #v >= 1.1.0
df %>% 
   mutate(counterpart_ID = rev(player_id), .by = c("group_id", "player_pair"))
```